# Common Validation filter for Servlet-Jsp project

Tags: java, validation, servlets, special-characters, servlet-filters

Is it possible to implement common filter to each response using a filter to **restrict Special Characters** in the response data just like we implement Interrupters in Spring Framework.

Comment: This has a strong smell of a http://xyproblem.info. What exactly is it, the problem for which you possibly incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution? Perhaps you're trying to solve XSS vulnerabilities in the webapp this way? If so, this needs definitely to be solved differently.

Comment: Yes i want to solve CSS attack, What is the solution instead of Server Side Validation.

Comment: It's XSS, not CSS. There's no need to validate it. Just make sure you escape all user-controlled data while outputting HTML.